# Why do I get SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have a `map()` and I want to pass two parameters:

1. a string
2. a function

Example code:

```js
{
  values.map((workflow, totalWorkflow()) => {
    return <WorkflowSingle key={ workflow } workflow={ workflow } />
  })
}
```

Why do I get this error: `SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue`

Comment: Any idea why you want to pass two params? No. What did you actually mean to ask?

Comment: Ah, sry too tired. I got this error:  Assigning to rvalue. Just edited the question as well.

Comment: What is the `map` function? Is it `Array.prototype.map` function?

Comment: I had this error when using code like this: `<input v-model="val + 'suffix'" />`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `map` function is the `Array.prototype.map` function, you passed wrong parameters to the function, `map` accepts callback and second optional parameter, like this:

> arr.map(callback[, thisArg])

For your case:

```
values.map(function(x) {
    return <WorkflowSingle key = { x.workflow } workflow = { x.workflow } />
});
```

Comment: yes. `return _.uniq(Mykit.find({createdBy: Meteor.userId()}, {sort: {workflow: 1}, fields: {workflow: true}}).fetch().map(function(x) {
   return x.workflow;`

Comment: upvote not working till 15 points. I'm new on sw. accepted. thanks again

Answer (score 30):

You get `rvalue` error, when you use `=` instead of `==` in a condition checking block.

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here getting this eslint error in a new project with completely valid code - you need to provide the config to eslint, e.g.:

```
{
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2017
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Look at your comparison operator. They are in the wrong direction (=>). Put the equal to sign always at the right and your less or greater than always at the left of your assignment operator(>=)

Comment: It's not being used for comparison.  It's an arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions